# Golang массив структур

Tags: golang, struct, golang-struct

Хочу создать `N` количество структур с прокси-данными чтоб потом по ним можно было пройтись при помощи `range`. То есть я мог бы сделать вот так

```
type Proxy struct {
    Addr []string
    User []string
    Password []string
}
```

И это прекрасно работает, но выглядит как-то не эстетично, как я думаю, лучше было бы использовать `[]Proxy` структуру без массивов `Addr, User, Password`, вид структуры `Proxy` был бы такой:

```
type Proxy struct {
    Addr string
    User string
    Password string
}
```

А сам код был бы такой, но код неправильный:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ProxyAuth struct {
    User, Password string
}

type Proxy struct {
    Type int
    Addr string

    Auth *ProxyAuth
}

func New() *[]Proxy {
    var arr []Proxy
    return &arr
}

func (p *[]Proxy) Add(addr, user, pass string) {
    pnew := Proxy{
        Type: 0xff,
        Addr: addr,

        Auth: &ProxyAuth{
            User:     user,
            Password: pass,
        },
    }
    p = append(p, pnew)
}

func main() {
    p := New()
    p.Add("192.168.0.1", "test", "test")

    for i := range p {
        fmt.Println(p.Addr, p.Auth.User, p.Auth.Password)
    }
}
```

Ошибки:

```
invalid receiver type *[]Proxy ([]Proxy is not a defined type)(undefined)
p.Add undefined (type *[]Proxy has no field or method Add)(undefined)
```

Как это можно сделать более грамотно и правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас сразу несколько ошибок. Во-первых, нельзя объявлять методы на срезы типов, не создав нового типа. Так что:

```golang
type Proxies []Proxy
```

Во-вторых, в методе `Add` параметр `p` является указателем:

```
*p = append(*p, pnew)
```

В-третьих, вы неправильно используете цикл:

```
for _, pp := range *p {
    fmt.Println(pp.Addr, pp.Auth.User, pp.Auth.Password)
}
```

Вот рабочий код: https://play.golang.org/p/JFgkla1tl7A.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь понял свои ошибки :)